# Open foundation zurb dropdown programmatically

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm building a shopping-cart with the foundation dropdown so i need a way to open the dropdown programmatically.
Is there any way?

I tried this:

```
$(document).foundation('dropdown', 'open', ($('#top-bar-cart'), $('.top-bar-cart-link'));
```

this:

```
Foundation.libs.dropdown.open($('#top-bar-cart'), $('.top-bar-cart-link'));
```

And this:

```
$('.dropdown-btn').trigger('click');
```

But no succes so far.

**EDIT:**

I think I found the problem.
I was using the code inside a click event to test it so I needed this:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

to make it work.
Full example:

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  // use this (most correct way, I think)
  Foundation.libs.dropdown.open($('#top-bar-cart'), $('.top-bar-cart-link'));
  // or this
  //('.top-bar-cart-link').trigger('click');
});
```

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k1gonvvc/ this works

Comment: The second and third option work, the first one won't. You should provide a complete example as your error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: This is the only working solution I found for this question. The e.preventDefault(); and  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); are the key bits to get this working. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.dropdown-btn').trigger('click.fndtn.dropdown')` instead of `.trigger('click')` ... as Foundation namespaces its events.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html#js-functions), this is how you should do it:

```
$('#top-bar-cart, .top-bar-cart-link').foundation('open');
```

...or if you initialized the dropdown yourself:

```
const dropdown = new Foundation.Dropdown($('#dropdown'))
dropdown.open()
```